# In PHP, how to act on the first 5 items in an array

Tags: php

PHP newbie...

I have connected to my database and retrieved the results of a query. The results are in an array called $result (original, I know).

Now I only want to act on the first 5 rows before doing something else with the rest. Basically, I want a table with 5 rows in it, then a new table with the next 5, etc. until all rows are used.

I can show all of the rows in one table, but can't figure out how to break them up like mentioned.

Any help? Thanks!

I think that array_chunk is what I am looking for, but I can't quite get it to work. I have tried this but get no results:

```
foreach(array_chunk($result, 5) as $chunk){
foreach ($chunk as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td><b>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</b></td></tr><tr><td>";
    echo $row['Time_Start2'];
    echo '</td></tr><tr><td><p align="justify">';
    echo $row['location'].". ".$row['details'];
    echo "</p></td></tr></br>";
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Looks like what you are trying to do is related to pagination.
In many websites, you get a number of records per page (5 in your case) and then you get links to move between pages. There are several tutorials that discuss pagination.

Comment: Are you sure `$result` is an array and not a query result?

Comment: array_chunk got me what I needed. Actually, I found an array_chunk_vertical function that is almost perfect. I have got it to work and am moving forward. Thanks for helping me get in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split your array up into "chunks" or "groups", see [array_chunk()](http://php.net/array_chunk)

```
foreach (array_chunk($data, 5) as $key => $chunk) {
   // $chunk will contain 5 items
   foreach ($chunk as $row) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Update (add to) your question with examples of what's not working with you.

Comment: Updated original post.

Answer (score 1):

Two examples:

```
while($five = array_slice($result, 0, 5)) {
    //loop $five array and output table
}

//or

foreach(array_chunk($result, 5) as $five) {
    //loop $five array and output table
}
```